# What does getattr() do and how to call functions dynamically (Python)

Tags: python

I know this is a duplicate but I don't understand previous answers, so I'm trying anyway.

I need to call different functions, all with the same name, from different classes.

so lets say I have this :

```
names = ["classA", "classB"]
for a in names:
    value = a.function()
```

How can I do this easily?
I don't understand exactly what getattr() does and how it can help me with my problem.

PS - I'm not a native English speaker, so please explain me as simply as possible

Comment: Why not have `names` be `[classA, classB]`, with the actual classes, so you don't need to use `getattr` or `locals`.

Comment: Your question is how to resolve the name of a class as string to the actual class. To which the counter-question is: why try that in the first place?

Comment: do i need to import classA and classB to do this?

Comment: Yes, otherwise nobody knows what `"classA"` refers to in the first place.

Comment: thank you, it works. I can now safely delete this thread :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem specifically you'll have to instantiate the class and then call the function, no need to use the getattr

```
names = [ClassA, ClassB] # no quotes here, just the class reference
for name in names:
    name().method()
```

If the classes have the same methods name this will work.